# Why did I lose 24 rep points with no notice?

Tags: support, reputation

I just lost 24 rep points and I don't know why?

Comment: Are you sure it was 24? I see -18 today on your activity. There might be something you can see that I cannot, though.

Comment: @Obie2.0, I am pretty sure I saw the -18 and my rep was at 3,614, then checking again it was what it is now.

Comment: Can you see anything on your activity?

Comment: @Obie2.0, no, I just can't see why this would happen. Can someone unmarking your answer as accpted make you lose this many points?

Comment: Ah, I think one of your question/answer pairs was deleted.

Comment: @Obie2.0, what one?

Comment: I am working on an answer.

Comment: @Obie2.0, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

### One of your answers  was deleted

You wrote a question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132681/can-we-use-turbo-boost-to-jump-a-car)<sup>1</sup>, asking whether Turbo Boost could be used to jump a car. You also answered that question.

[image]
As you can see, your answer has 3 upvotes and 3 downvotes, for a net reputation gain of 3*10-3*2 = 24 reputation. When the question was deleted, you lost that reputation.

[image]

### Why was the question deleted?

The deletion reason was given as RemovedAbandonedClosed. As noted [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/roomba), a question is deleted:

> **If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days

All of these conditions were met on your question, and so the Community user deleted it.

At some point, you should have seen (or should see) a gain of 2 reputation as well, since your net -2 on the question should also be reversed.

If you wish to view your deleted posts, you have several options:

- If you have more than 10,000 reputation the `deleted:1` search term should be of some assistance.
- If the question was deleted recently, a high-reputation user might be able to see it, if you really need access.

<sub><sup><sup>1</sup> link only available for 10K+ rep users</sup></sub>

Comment: Why did that happen?

Comment: @KyloRen - The second part of the answer explains why. It was an automatic process. If you had accepted an answer, for example, it would not have happened. It is basically a way of gauging community interest.

Comment: @KyloRen - The Community user (process, really) is a moderator, and such I *believe* you cannot undelete it. You could appeal to a moderator to have it undeleted, but given that the post is off-topic, that is probably unlikely to happen.

Comment: OK, I am going to state for the record, that this web site is the most biased , ridiculous and heavy handed web site on the internet. In this link, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=36&tab=votes  There are way more threads that meet those criteria that are still available.  As i have alawys maintained, it depends on the user as to who's thread get deleted. Honestly, I am fed up.

Comment: @KyloRen - The questions that you referenced do not meet those criteria, since they were not closed. While individual users may certainly be biased, the Community user is a *process*.

Comment: As I said, it depends on the user.

Comment: @KyloRen - While human moderators may indeed show favoritism, your question was deleted *automatically* due to a set of criteria, laid out above. One of those is being closed, which the unanswered questions that you showed are not. The roomba may or may not be fair, but it does not depend on the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41967/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-kyloren).